# Can we fetch data using JPA without using primary key

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

My Table:

| Emotion |
| --- |
| EID (Primary Key) |
| user_mood |
| Latitude |
| Longitude |
| uid |

```
@Entity
public class Emotion
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer eId;
    @Column(name = "user_mood")
    private String mood;
    private String latitude;
    private String longitude;
    private String uid;

}
```

My Interface:

```
public interface EmotionRepository extends JpaRepository<Emotion, String>{}
```

When I try to fetch values using uid
**emotionRepo.findById(uid)**
I am getting below type mismatch error

Error message:

```
org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class mood_sensor.mood_sensor.pojos.Emotion. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.String
```

Can I retrieve data using uid or I should use only the primaryKey(Integer) to retrieve data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but the method `findById`, from `CrudRepository<T, ID>` always expect to receive the ID as the argument - see **[here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#findById-ID-)** (be aware that `JpaRepository` extends from `CrudRepository`).

You can query by another field in a variety of ways, but as I saw that your use case is pretty simple, I'd suggest you to make use of Spring Data's query creation deriving from the method's name - see **[here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)** and **[here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords)**

It's really simple, just create a method called `findByUid` in your `EmotionRepository` and Spring will take care of the rest by deriving the desired query from the method's name:

```java
public interface EmotionRepository extends JpaRepository<Emotion, Integer> {
    Optional<Emotion> findByUid(String uid);
}
```

Spring Data will then generate something like the following query:

`SELECT e.* FROM Emotion e WHERE e.uid = <the-value>`

Now, you can use `findByUid` method to query using the `uid` field.

And another fix: change from

`EmotionRepository extends JpaRepository<Emotion, String>`

to

`EmotionRepository extends JpaRepository<Emotion, Integer>`

this is because the id from `Emotion` is of type `Integer`, not `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `JpaRepository` (`EmotionRepository`), you can make a function signature, anmd and the JPA will create a method to fetch whatever data you need.

This doc should help you understand exactly what is happening: http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/1.0.0.M1/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation